# Python script to convert from numbers to words for printing cheques

Tags: python

I think I can avoid reinventing the wheel here.

I need a Python script to convert from numbers to words for printing cheques.

E.g. `1,10,543` should provide output as `One lac ten thousand five hundred and forty three`.

Comment: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/10/21/python-converting-numbers-to-words/

Comment: @NPE: This script provides output in the format "one hundred ten thousand , five hundred forty three". Not very cheque-friendly.

Comment: It seems you need it for India locale context, and its hard to get one as such but you can customize the above script to suit your purpose

Comment: Could you explain the desired format in more detail? Maybe it's just my ignorance, but I'm not sure how 1,10,543 is a valid number or what a lac is.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no ready solution for this kind of task. You will have to write a converter yourself.

Comment: @BrianMarshall Its a unit of measurement representing one hundred thousand; see [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have written a custom converter with the foll features:

- Number to Word converter that can be used for numbers from 0 to 999999999
  catering to Indian subcontinent i.e. lacs and crore (The range is big
  enough to accomodate lot of use cases)
- Includes paisa support upto 2 decimal places (rounded)
- Inspired by the post at http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/10/21/python-converting-numbers-to-words/
- Profiling information: This script has lesser performace in terms of execution time of 0.458 seconds against 0.237 seconds of the above script for exactly 10000 runs.

  ```
  class Number2Words(object):

          def __init__(self):
              '''Initialise the class with useful data'''

              self.wordsDict = {1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three', 4: 'four', 5: 'five', 6: 'six', 7: 'seven',
                                8: 'eight', 9: 'nine', 10: 'ten', 11: 'eleven', 12: 'twelve', 13: 'thirteen',
                                14: 'fourteen', 15: 'fifteen', 16: 'sixteen', 17: 'seventeen',
                                18: 'eighteen', 19: 'nineteen', 20: 'twenty', 30: 'thirty', 40: 'forty',
                                50: 'fifty', 60: 'sixty', 70: 'seventy', 80: 'eighty', 90: 'ninty' }

              self.powerNameList = ['thousand', 'lac', 'crore']


          def convertNumberToWords(self, number):

              # Check if there is decimal in the number. If Yes process them as paisa part.
              formString = str(number)
              if formString.find('.') != -1:
                  withoutDecimal, decimalPart = formString.split('.')

                  paisaPart =  str(round(float(formString), 2)).split('.')[1]
                  inPaisa = self._formulateDoubleDigitWords(paisaPart)

                  formString, formNumber = str(withoutDecimal), int(withoutDecimal)
              else:
                  # Process the number part without decimal separately
                  formNumber = int(number)
                  inPaisa = None

              if not formNumber:
                  return 'zero'

              self._validateNumber(formString, formNumber)

              inRupees = self._convertNumberToWords(formString)

              if inPaisa:
                  return 'Rs. %s and %s paisa' % (inRupees.title(), inPaisa.title())
              else:
                  return 'Rs. %s' % inRupees.title()


          def _validateNumber(self, formString, formNumber):

              assert formString.isdigit()

              # Developed to provide words upto 999999999
              if formNumber > 999999999 or formNumber < 0:
                  raise AssertionError('Out Of range')


          def _convertNumberToWords(self, formString):

              MSBs, hundredthPlace, teens = self._getGroupOfNumbers(formString)

              wordsList = self._convertGroupsToWords(MSBs, hundredthPlace, teens)

              return ' '.join(wordsList)


          def _getGroupOfNumbers(self, formString):

              hundredthPlace, teens = formString[-3:-2], formString[-2:]

              msbUnformattedList = list(formString[:-3])

              #---------------------------------------------------------------------#

              MSBs = []
              tempstr = ''
              for num in msbUnformattedList[::-1]:
                  tempstr = '%s%s' % (num, tempstr)
                  if len(tempstr) == 2:
                      MSBs.insert(0, tempstr)
                      tempstr = ''
              if tempstr:
                  MSBs.insert(0, tempstr)

              #---------------------------------------------------------------------#

              return MSBs, hundredthPlace, teens


          def _convertGroupsToWords(self, MSBs, hundredthPlace, teens):

              wordList = []

              #---------------------------------------------------------------------#
              if teens:
                  teens = int(teens)
                  tensUnitsInWords = self._formulateDoubleDigitWords(teens)
                  if tensUnitsInWords:
                      wordList.insert(0, tensUnitsInWords)

              #---------------------------------------------------------------------#
              if hundredthPlace:
                  hundredthPlace = int(hundredthPlace)
                  if not hundredthPlace:
                      # Might be zero. Ignore.
                      pass
                  else:
                      hundredsInWords = '%s hundred' % self.wordsDict[hundredthPlace]
                      wordList.insert(0, hundredsInWords)

              #---------------------------------------------------------------------#
              if MSBs:
                  MSBs.reverse()

                  for idx, item in enumerate(MSBs):
                      inWords = self._formulateDoubleDigitWords(int(item))
                      if inWords:
                          inWordsWithDenomination = '%s %s' % (inWords, self.powerNameList[idx])
                          wordList.insert(0, inWordsWithDenomination)

              #---------------------------------------------------------------------#
              return wordList


          def _formulateDoubleDigitWords(self, doubleDigit):

              if not int(doubleDigit):
                  # Might be zero. Ignore.
                  return None
              elif self.wordsDict.has_key(int(doubleDigit)):
                  # Global dict has the key for this number
                  tensInWords = self.wordsDict[int(doubleDigit)]
                  return tensInWords
              else:
                  doubleDigitStr = str(doubleDigit)
                  tens, units = int(doubleDigitStr[0])*10, int(doubleDigitStr[1])
                  tensUnitsInWords = '%s %s' % (self.wordsDict[tens], self.wordsDict[units])
                  return tensUnitsInWords


  if __name__ == '__main__':

      wGenerator = Number2Words()
      print wGenerator.convertNumberToWords(100000)
  ```

Comment: The above is not valid for **Python3 (has_key is not available in Python3)**, Please use the following gist for Python3: [Gist for Python 3 version of the class](https://gist.github.com/puneetkaura/f5b7592310511db6047ded4b31c77710)

Answer (score 3):

You can use  the python library [num2words](https://github.com/savoirfairelinux/num2words) (`pip install num2words`):

Example:

```
from num2words import num2words
num2words(110543, to='cardinal', lang='en_IN')
```

Output:

```
'one lakh, ten thousand, five hundred and forty-three'
```