# Django template How to Convert numbers to Words

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I am searching for a template tag to convert a value like 522 to five hundred twenty two only. Looking in docs i came across

> django.contrib.humanize

which has a build in tag intword but it works only with number with numbers greater than a million.

as a alternative solution i have created a tag using function from 
[Python script to convert from numbers to words for printing cheques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913165/python-script-to-convert-from-numbers-to-words-for-printing-cheques/13932483#13932483)

kindly suggest if any better solution possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out this library: [num2words](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/num2words)

Straight from the docs:

```
>>> from num2words import num2words
>>> num2words(42)
forty-two
>>> num2words(42, ordinal=True)
forty-second
>>> num2words(42, lang='fr')
quarante-deux
```

Comment: thanks this works for me i could create custom django tag using the library.